# Jar signing -validity property

Tags: keytool, self-signed, jar-signing, jarsigner

I used the -validity property of the keytool to generate a keystore and self sign a jar. During the process, I saw the debug message that says

```
 [info] Warning:
 [info] This jar contains entries whose signer certificate will expire within six
 months.
```

I am using the following commands,

```
keytool -genkey -alias signFiles -keypass mypass  -keystore mystore -storepass mypass-alias store -validity 365
keytool -selfcert -keystore mystore -alias store
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Actually I wanted to sign the jar with a certificate for 1 year.

Cheers,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-validity 365` to your `-selfcert` command.